# Feature Request: Cancel Button for Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-usage, answering-questions, troubleshooting

There have been a few situations where I began to answer a question and realized that my answer was more of a comment.  I copied that info into the comment feature and posted that way.  However, when I come back, I can't delete the data in the answer field.  I assumed some of this was stored in a cookie, but obviously that isn't the case.  I didn't find anything about this in other Meta questions or in the FAQ (I could have missed something.)

It seems like the point to this is to recover answers if pages crash or are closed.  However, I just want to cancel my answer entirely.  There is no 'cancel' button for answers and I don't think it's proper use to post an empty answer.  Does anyone else experience this?  What should I do to clear out the answer field?  And finally, can we have a "Cancel" button?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Due to comments:  Browser - Firefox 7.0.1

This appears to be happening only on one specific case now:  [Wordpress is asking for FTP, is it some package missing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/323585/wordpress-is-asking-for-ftp-is-it-some-package-missing)

The other instances are not showing the issue any longer.  This Question was moved from another StackExchange site.  Is it possibly related?

Comment: This doesn't happen to me, I can delete the content of the answer field whenever I want. What browser?

Comment: Also, since this would impact all Se sites, it really belongs on Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: Firefox 7.0.1.  It occurred to me that it might be some sort of browser issue.  Figures!  Sorry for the spam in that case.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 7.0.1. Can you list exact steps?

Comment: Not really meaning to be a jerk... I login and click on my post and it prepopulates the answer field with what I had typed(one that i'd previously typed in but didn't click "Post".)  That's it... in the answer window, i see what I had previously typed, but no cancel link appears.  I can screenshot and email if you like.  I've tried dumping all the cache, cookies - typical stuff.  No joy.

Comment: Hm. And you can't delete the text from the answer field?

Comment: Oh I can.  It just reappears when i reload the page.

Comment: I'll test it with this post and see if it happens again... and I'm trying... and no, it doesn't appear to be happening on this page.

Comment: I must say I am *most thankful* that there is no `Cancel` button... it is one of those things you tend to press accidentally *much* more often than when you need it. Especially since Iain's answer below points out that you only need to start another answer somewhere else for your autosave to get deleted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the draft [autosave](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting) feature at work. It remembers the content of the last answer you typed until you either post the answer or start to write an answer to a different question, at which point it gets auto saved. Drafts fade away after one week.

Comment: and it doesn't have a cancel feature?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of it just fades away...

Comment: Thank you.  It might be worthwhile to mention this in the FAQ section.  Someone else has to have wondered what was going on.

Comment: ... so if you really want to get rid of your draft directly, you can replace it by `.` and wait for the next autosave to kick in (notice the `draft saved` message below the edit box) ;-)